# How can I share a Basic Authentication header across a Collection in Postman?

Tags: postman, artifactory

I have a collection of basic API queries against our local JFrog Artifactory swarm to test whether or not the version of a requested library has been made available on our enterprise package manager.

As an example, I'll use angular.

```
https://artifactory.foo.com/artifactory/api/storage/npm-approved/angular/-
```

This returns a nice little list of versions that are available.

I have a test running against this particular query to ensure the appropriate version is available in said result set.

```
var neededVersion = '1.4.14';

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var versions = jsonData.children;
var hasNeededVersion = false;

for(var version in versions) {
   if(versions[version].uri.indexOf(neededVersion) >= 0) {
       hasNeededVersion = true;
   }
}

tests[neededVersion] = hasNeededVersion;
```

Great tool, as with the 40+ libraries I'm constantly needing to get updates on, I have a collection of queries to all our project dependencies in the same manner. I invoke the runner and point it at the collection and review all my test results. HUGE improvement.

Then I had to change my password.

I had to go through and update the 'Authentication' header for each and every entry. This seems arduous. I looked into setting the header in Environments and globals, but nothing seemed to work.

The thought would be to just update my credentials in one place.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Currently, how do you set your pass? Do you define it as a variable in each script? Or are you using it as part of your REST API call? 
How are you calling the REST API call, from within a script? if so why not using a variable for storing the password and using it on all of your scripts. 
If you are using multiple scripts, not in the same "master script" then why not storing your credentials in a separate file, and read the params from each script. 
Sorry in advance if those already crossed your mind, it's just not obvious from your question.

Comment: And one last thing, if you are not using a "master script", why not creating a master script that stores the credentials and passes it when it invokes each of your scripts one after another?

Comment: Currently, I just add the Basic Auth header. The API call is handled either by manually 'sending' it or opening the 'runner' and selecting the collection and running it. I am not familiar enough with Postman (yet) to know the 'master script' and its potential.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've overlooked that you are using Postman..

Answer (score 0):

Type the username:password in [this online tool](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to get the Authentication header

admin:1234 in base64 is YWRtaW46MTIzNA==

In Postman, goto Settings - Manage Environments - Globals and add a global variable called basic_auth with a value of Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==

In each request go to the request Headers and add a key Authorization with a value of {{basic_auth}}

Then when the password changes you can update the global variable and all requests will use the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving the Auth header, try setting your username and password in the Authorization tab. Postman will use that info to create the Authorization header when the request is sent. Then you would be able to use Environment Variables (or even collection variables) which would only need to be updated **in one place**.

**Instructions:**

1. Set up environment/collection variables for 'username' and 'password', and save
2. In each request:
3. In the Heaaders tab, remove the Authorization header
4. In the Authorization tab, select the Type: Basic Auth
5. In the Username field, enter {{username}}
6. For the Password field, click "Show Password", and enter
   {{password}}

Hope this helps others :)